# Getting number of elements in a file

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I am new to C programming and I want to write elements from a bin. file into a dinamically alocated array. The problem is that I dont know how many elements (1 element is user defined struct) that file has so I dont know how to allocate arry for placing those elements from file.

I dont know if I explained well, I have a file "students.txt" (I still want to use it as binary), and it consits of N students.
Now I want to read students to a dinamicaly allocated array.
Problem is that I dont know a way to find the number of students in file in order to allocate memory in array for that number of students.

so is there any function that returns number of elements of sertian type from a file?

I know that

```
int fread(void *array, int size, int count, FILE *dat);
```

returns number of elements but I also need to specify array where files are going to be written and i dont have that array allocated yet.
Sorry if I made this too complicated I hope you understand my problem nad sorry for eng. it is not my native lang.

The definition of the `struct`:

```
typedef struct
{
   char indeks[8];
   char ime[21];
   char prezime[21];
   double prosjek;
} STUDENT;
```

Comment: For situations like this you don't necessarily need to know the number of elements before hand. The general approach is to use dynamic memory allocation (`malloc` and/or `realloc`). So that you can grow your array as required (or use something like a linked list - depending on your requirements).

Comment: Please post the definition of *student*.

Comment: Or if you really need to know the numer of elements and the structures are fixed size, there's nothing else in the file and you trust the integrity of the file then you can get the file size and divide by the structure (binary) size.

Comment: I know how to use it usually with malloc and realloc but in this case I cant. I need to know the number of elements beffore allocating.

Comment: def of studnet: `typedef struct
{
 char indeks[8];
 char ime[21];
 char prezime[21];
 double prosjek;
}STUDENT;`

Comment: Why do you necesarily need to know beforehand? Just allocate some memory, say for 100 elements, then start reading one structure at a time. If you reach 100 then call realloc to increase the array size and keep reading structures. That's just a simplified illustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you will not have issues reading the structures (e.g., you saved structure which contained `int` with size 4bytes and try to read on machine where `int` is different size, etc.) - just get the file size in bytes - and divide on the size of the structure.

Comment: @NebojsaTosic In case you forgot: You can figure out the size of a structure with the `sizeof` operator.

Comment: @NebojsaTosic:just hopefully you have taken care of issues which may arise when writing structures to files in binary way(google for that)

Comment: That is very bad design practice. What if the program is executed on a different platform, with different endianess or scaler sizes or even just different compiler-settings? or even Strings with utf8 encoding? Reading a file should never depend on internal types of a platform.